# How to "log in" to wifi hotspot from Apple TV

Tags: network, wifi, appletv

Our home internet service is late being installed, but I discovered that there is a "hot spot" from my provider that I am able to log in to from my PC.  This requires that I enter some credentials at a special web page or something before I can access the network.  But when I connect to the same hot spot from my Apple TV it says I am connected, but it never prompts me for credentials and says there is no Internet connection.

I read somewhere that under Settings > Users and Accounts > TV Providers I should be able to log in to *something* although I'm not sure if this will let me log into a WiFi hotspot.  When I try to log in I get the message "Bag Load Error" so I can't tell what is supposed to happen here.

How can I log in to the WiFi hotspot from Apple TV?

Comment: Hi @michael, I've not tried it but perhaps using Mac Address Spoofing to authorize the AppleTV mac address [as suggested by this article on using in hotel](https://robpickering.com/using-an-apple-tv-on-hotel-wifi-captive-portal/)??  The TV Provider login is because the providers want you to authenticate so they can track what you watch - nothing to do with WiFi

Comment: @MrR Not sure what the problem is... maybe a router somewhere remembers the MAC address of the Apple TV, but when I try to spoof the MAC from my PC, it suddenly can't access anything.

Comment: Hi @Michael - remember it needs to be the WiFi mac address (so you work out the Apple TV values, turn it off, then set up on your laptop, connect, do the auth thing, then you flip you laptop back to normal and turn Apple TV on .... And perhaps there's something else going on too [i.e. the Wifi connect causes something else]...

Comment: @MrR I unplugged the Apple TV overnight and was able to spoof it in the morning.